# jQuery not working in Internet Explorer 11 when dealing with <select><option>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

**UPDATE: AT this point I am able to open the subjects in IE-11 but not close.  The spans are not being placed back on the objects to handle the display:none.**

Why am I not able to select a specific option with jQuery when I am forced to use IE?

In a SELECT I have a list of 'Subjects' (OPTION's) and under each 'Subject' there are 'Courses'.

All of these are OPTION's are setup with class of '.subject' or '.course'

When the page loads it should show ONLY the 'Subjects' and when a 'Subject' is clicked it should accordion open to display all of the 'Courses' that are part of that 'Subject'.  When clicking that same 'Subject' it should close the 'Subject'.  If a different 'Subject' is clicked, it should close all 'Subjects' and then open the newly clicked 'Subject'.

Simplified question being, what is the best way of using jQuery to access a select option when it is clicked since IE does not allow options to be set as the selector?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tsoheili/7p222pur/16/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
function showCourses(i) {
    //hideCourses();
    $('.subject.subject-' + i).addClass('open');
    $('.course.subject-' + i).toggleOption(true);
    $('.child.subject-' + i).toggleOption(true);
}
// function hideCourses() {
//  $('#selectable_box .course').toggleOption(false);
//  $('#selectable_box .child').toggleOption(false);
//  $('.open').removeClass('open');
// }
// function hideCourses(i) {
//  $('#selectable_box .course.subject-' + i).toggleOption(false);
//  $('#selectable_box .child.subject-' + i).toggleOption(false);
//  $('.open').removeClass('open');
// }

function showSubjects(i) {
    var link = '.subject.subject-' + i;
    var content = '.subject-' + i;
    // hideCourses();
    // hideCourses(i);
}

var numSubjects = $('.subject').length;

for(var i = 1; i <= numSubjects; i++) {
    showSubjects(i);
}

function Redirect() {
    //window.location="https://www.bwreporting.net/index.php?option=com_bwreporting&view=report&Itemid=412&uid={$uid}&zk=11zCfScZtD2ms9LyBZ4UySgYH";
    var cus_url ='{$page_url}{$report_details->custom_page_url_1}';
    console.log(cus_url);
    //window.top.location.href=cus_url;
}

function AddCourses(){
    //setTimeout('Redirect()', 500);
    var cus_url ='{$page_url}{$report_details->custom_page_url_1}';
    window.top.location.href=cus_url;

}

function SelectAllItems() {
    var valArray = [];

    $("#selected_box  option").each(function () {
    txtVal = $(this).text();
    valArray.push({title:txtVal,loid:$(this).val()});
    });
    $('#hidden1').val(JSON.stringify(valArray));
}

//Method to handle displaying and not displaying courses when the subjects are clicked.
jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};
//jQuery(selector).toggleOption(true); // show option
//jQuery(selector).toggleOption(false); // hide option

$('#selectable_box option.course').toggleOption(false);
$('#selectable_box option.child').toggleOption(false);

var options = $("#selectable_box :selected");
var lastOption;
var subj_id;
var i;
var open;
var len;

$("#selectable_box").click(function()
{
    lastOption = $(this).find(':selected').not(options);
    options = $(this).find(':selected');

    subj_id = options.attr('class');
    end = subj_id.length;
    start = end - 4;

    open = subj_id.substring(start, end);

    if(subj_id != '' || subj_id != 'undefined') {
        if(open == 'open') {
            $('#selectable_box option.course').toggleOption(false);
        $('#selectable_box option.child').toggleOption(false);
        $('.open').removeClass('open');
        // hideCourses();
        }else{
            i = subj_id.replace('subject subject-', '');
            $('#selectable_box option.course').toggleOption(false);
        $('#selectable_box option.child').toggleOption(false);
        $('.open').removeClass('open');
            showCourses(i);
        }
    }else{
        $('#selectable_box option.course').toggleOption(false);
    $('#selectable_box option.child').toggleOption(false);
    $('.open').removeClass('open');
    }

});
</script>



    <form name='submit' id='myFormId' method='post' onsubmit='AddCourses()' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div id='main_content'>
    <div class='heading-row'>
<div class='heading-right' id='bypassme'><span id='buttonDiv'>
<div id='list' style='width:465px;float:left'>
<div class='header'>Select Courses <span class='small'>(Up to 30)</span></div><select style="width:300px;height : 300px" multiple="multiple" name="selectable_box" id="selectable_box">
<option class="subject subject-1" value="">Subject One</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="5" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="6" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="7" subj-id="1" class="course subject-1" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option class="subject subject-2" value="">Subject Two</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="5" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="6" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="7" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option data-key="8" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 8</option>
<option data-key="9" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 9</option>
<option data-key="10" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 10</option>
<option data-key="11" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 11</option>
<option data-key="12" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 12</option>
<option data-key="13" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 13</option>
<option data-key="14" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 14</option>
<option data-key="15" subj-id="2" class="course subject-2" value="" style="">Course 15</option>
<option class="subject subject-3" value="">Subject Three</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="3" class="course subject-3" value="" style="">"Course 1"</option>
<option class="subject subject-4" value="">Subject Four</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">"Course 1"</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="5" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="6" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="7" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option data-key="8" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 8</option>
<option data-key="9" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 9</option>
<option data-key="10" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 10</option>
<option data-key="11" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 11</option>
<option data-key="12" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 12</option>
<option data-key="13" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 13</option>
<option data-key="14" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 14</option>
<option data-key="15" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 15</option>
<option data-key="16" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 16</option>
<option data-key="17" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 17</option>
<option data-key="18" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 18</option>
<option data-key="19" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 19</option>
<option data-key="20" subj-id="4" class="course subject-4" value="" style="">Course 20</option>
<option class="subject subject-5" value="">Subject Five</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="5" class="course subject-5" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option class="subject subject-6" value="">Subject Six</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="5" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="6" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="7" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option data-key="8" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 8</option>
<option data-key="9" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 9</option>
<option data-key="10" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 10</option>
<option data-key="11" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 11</option>
<option data-key="12" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 12</option>
<option data-key="13" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 13</option>
<option data-key="14" subj-id="6" class="course subject-6" value="" style="">Course 14</option>
<option class="subject subject-7" value="">Subject Seven</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="5" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="6" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="7" subj-id="7" class="course subject-7" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option class="subject subject-8" value="">Subject Eight</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="8" class="course subject-8" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="8" class="course subject-8" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="8" class="course subject-8" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="8" class="course subject-8" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option class="subject subject-9" value="">Subject Nine</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="9" class="course subject-9" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="2" subj-id="9" class="course subject-9" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="3" subj-id="9" class="course subject-9" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="4" subj-id="9" class="course subject-9" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option class="subject subject-10" value="">Subject Ten</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child One</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child Two</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child Three</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child Four</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child Five</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 3</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 4</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 5</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 6</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 7</option>
<option class="child subject-10" value="">Child Six</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 1</option>
<option data-key="1" subj-id="10" class="course subject-10" value="" style="">Course 2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div style='min-width:65px;float:left'>&nbsp;<button id='add' type='button' style='cursor:default;' title='Add' class='gen_btn'>&nbsp;</button><button id='remove' type='button' style='cursor:default;' title='Remove' class='gen_btn' >&nbsp;</button></div>
<div id='list' style='width:465px;float:left'>
<div class='header'>Your Queue <input type='submit' name='submit' class='gen_btn' value='Save Queue & Generate Report' onmouseover='SelectAllItems()'></div>
<select style="width:300px;" multiple="mutiple" name="selected_box" id="selected_box">

</select>
</div>
<div style='margin:50px;width:465px;float:left'><input type='hidden' id='hidden1' name='hidden1[]' value='' /><input type='hidden' id='sneak' name='sneak' value='1' /></div><br style='clear:both;'></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class='cat-list-row'>
<div class='heading-left'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please start using stylesheets for everyones sake.

Comment: UPDATE: AT this point I am able to open the subjects in IE-11 but not close. The spans are not being placed back on the objects to handle the display:none.

Comment: jQuery.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
    jQuery( this ).toggle( show );
    if( show ) {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length )
            jQuery( this ).unwrap( );
    } else {
        if( jQuery( this ).parent( 'span.toggleOption' ).length == 0 )
            jQuery( this ).wrap( '<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />' );
    }
};

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support click on options, use the onchange event on the select.